# Why can't Boxen use RVM?

Tags: rvm, boxen

I understand that [Boxen](http://boxen.github.com/) doesn't work with [RVM](http://rvm.io/), what I don't understand is why. Is there some limitation that prevents Boxen from being able to use RVM instead of rbenv? The core of Boxen is Puppet which does support the installation of an RVM module so I'm not sure why this is the case. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: cause bro, just cause.

Answer (score 0):

Boxen uses rbenv.  rbenv is incompatible with RVM (plus there are mostly redundant).

For a good comparison of the two see this [blog post: rvm-and-rbenv](http://jonathan-jackson.net/rvm-and-rbenv)

Comment: Doesn't answer my question.

Comment: rbenv shims the ruby binaries. RVM wraps ruby binaries with aliases/functions in bash.  The two methods conflict.  I suppose if you made sure that everything that rbenv shims was aliased in the scripts that load RVM into the shell, you could pull it off.

you would then need to make sure that RVM and rbenv shared ruby installations.